# How to get HtmlDocument from Awesomium.WebControl

Tags: .net, winforms, web-controls, awesomium

I'm doing all this in a .Net winforms application.

I'm used to using the IE WebControl that just has a document property. Pretty simple.

Now I'm using the Awesomium.WebControl and I'm trying to get at the underlying document so I can do some DOM work.

But I can't see how to get at it.
Nor can I find any articles on how to do that in Google.

Can someone post some working code that starts with a WebControl and ends with an object that has all the DOM methods please? I don't care what class it is as long as it lets me go thru the dom collections and stuff.

I prefer to do my work in .Net and not in javascript.
but as a last resort, I'll take what works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the HTML document in your Awesomium WebControl you can execute a JavaScript `getElementsByTagName`.  This is how we do it:

```
Dim html As String = WebControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
```

For example, you can place this code in a handler for the `WebControl.DocumentReady` event.  Otherwise you need to have a check for `WebControl1.IsDocumentReady = True` before executing the JavaScript.

We then use the HTMLAgilityPack to parse this HTML string into a HTMLDocument:

```
Dim doc As New HtmlDocument
doc.LoadHtml(html)
```

which hopefully allows you to do all of the work you need to!

Comment: Thank you. Do you happen to know if the html returned by ExecuteJavascriptWithResult is post-javascript dom manipulation or the original unaltered code of the web page?

Comment: It will return the current state of the page.  So, if you do it after the `DocumentReady` event has fired it will be post-JavaScript dom manipulation.

Comment: This sort of works, except that DocumentReady is called before all asynchronous callbacks have completed. Is there a way to know when these have completed?